# Passing GET params to a Django View internally

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to call a Django view internally from another view:

```
response = BlogViewSet.as_view({'get':'list'})(request)
```

BlogViewSet is actually a rest framework view.
The above code works and I can access `response.data` but what I actually want to do is pass in some GET params to do some filtering. I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
response = BlogViewSet.as_view({'get':'list'})(request, my_param=something)
```

I realise I could modify `request` to add GET params but it seems wrong to modify it as it might be used later in the view.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't ever call the view itself form another view.

You should instead try to extract the meaningful data / code out of the `BlogViewSet` view and call them directly from the various views.

Comment: Unfortunately that's difficult because it's a django rest framework view with complex serializers and filters

Comment: I didn't say it was easy and it may be difficult due to tightly coupled design. You should be able to use serializers / filters outside the scope of `BlogViewSet`

Answer (score -1):

Calling one view from another is a bad practice.

Why not request url of the view instead of calling the view itself.

```
r = requests.get("<url_to_access_view>", params={})
```

Comment: Because it seems a bit pointless serializing it to json in the API, then deserializing it in my view, but you might be right.